# Loading Activex in PHP

Tags: php, activex

I'm trying to load an Activex in my PHP code, As I know this can be done with COM function in PHP, so I try to access my methods as below:

```
<?PHP
$active = new COM("sswATL.crypto");
//------------------------

$pass = "pincode";

$ret = $active->init( $pass , $retVal);

if($retVal == 0){ 
   print "Login successfully";
}
elseif($retVal == 4){

   print "Token is not present";
} 
else
{
   $errMsg = "Login failed : "; 
   print $errMsg;
  }
?>
```

but I got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception'
with message '<b>Source:</b> Unknown<br/><b>Description:</b> Unknown'
in C:\my\php\file\path.php
Stack trace:
#0 C:\my\php\file\path.php: com->init('pincode', NULL)
#1 {main}
thrown in C:\my\php\file\path.php on line 7
```

init method is declared as:

```
int init(string s,int &num);
```

any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to explicitly set `$retVal=0` before `init`?

Comment: Yes, I set '$retVal=0' before 'init', but got the same error.

Comment: I guess I have some problem with call by reference argument, I mean int &num, but I do not know how should I pass this type of arguments.

Comment: Weird, your stack trace said you're passing a `NULL` as second parameter, so my first guess was to pass an already defined (thus "not NULL") variable. Any chance you can "return" that value from some function call, avoiding variable reference?

Comment: I checked the declarations and unfortunately all of my methods return reference argument. any idea?

Comment: No clue here :( Last attempt: try `$retval=0;$active->init($pass,&$retVal);`?

Comment: No sense :( anyway thank you so much for your help